# ServiceFabric - ActorEventSource is not enabled

Tags: system.diagnostics, azure-service-fabric, eventsource

I am trying to trace some logs using ActorEventSource provided for Actors in ServiceFabric, but it appeared to be disabled. The control that fails is:
if (this.IsEnabled())
            { ... }

How can I enable it?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?  Having this very issue today out of the blue.

Comment: It was a problem of the software I used to trace them, without modifying anything it works now. I'll try to gather more information as soon as possible!